# Current month minus 5 months for all years worth of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data for the month 5 before the current one. I have tried

```
MONTH(GETDATE()) - MonthNum ='5'
```

Where `monthnum` has been parsed from the date in a previous CTE.

This works for the 6th month and beyond but doesn't for earlier months.

The end goal is, for example in November I can see data only for June, for all years not just the current one.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE MONTH(GETDATE()) - AnniMonthNum ='5'
```

Comment: Please add the full SQL that you have tried; input examples; expected output example; so we may best assist you here - include the table/column definition as it may alter the answer here.

Comment: Your issue is  how you account for the year scope for "This works for the 6th month and beyond but doesn't for earlier months."

Comment: Why not use `DATEADD`? `MONTH('20210101') -5` is going to give the "month" `-4`; there isn't a -4th month.

Comment: "The end goal is... I can see data... for all years". Are you asking for each year to be in a separate row? You're essentially computing a scalar in your code example which doesn't make sense in the context of the question. Are you just asking to limit a dataset to the month of June (or more specifically, 5 months prior to current month)? If so then `DECLARE @month = MONTH(DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())); SELECT * FROM table as t WHERE MONTH(t.transaction_date) = @month;` Clarify your question for an actual answer.

Comment: For example I want to see all the sales for every year for the current month minus 5 months. So in November I want to see all sales in all years for June

Comment: @arsenaql then my example will work for what you're trying to do. Instead of declaring a variable, you can take the the calculation and put it directly in the WHERE clause (if using an a view as opposed to using in a stored procedure or function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your clarification, try this:

```
DECLARE @month = MONTH(DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())); 

SELECT t.* 
FROM table as t 
WHERE MONTH(t.transaction_date) = @month;
```

or, if using in a view, substitute the calculation directly in the WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table as t 
WHERE MONTH(t.transaction_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE()));
```

If you already have the number of months calculated, then substitute that variable for the interval in the `DATEADD` function. Below I make sure the interval is negative by multiplying monthnum by -1.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table as t 
WHERE MONTH(t.transaction_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month,-1 * monthnum,GETDATE()));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using DateDiff

```
  where DateDiff(month,AnniversaryDate,GetDate)=5
```